GitLab runner with Docker: client version is too old issue
I Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS I have installed GitLab Runner that I want to use with Docker.
When I try to execute a job, I get following message:
Using Docker executor with image python:3.9.13-slim-buster ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: {"message":"client version 1.18 is too old. Minimum supported API version is 1.24, please upgrade your client to a newer version"} (executor_docker.go:1147:0s)

This quite strange since I have following version of Docker:
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           26.1.2
 API version:       1.45
 Go version:        go1.21.10
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          26.1.2
  API version:      1.45 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.21.10
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.31
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.12
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0

And GitLab Runner version is:
Version:      11.2.0
Git revision: 11.2.0
Git branch:   HEAD
GO version:   go1.10.4
Built:        unknown
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

I tried for almost a day to find some solution, but nothing yet. I am not sure from where this client version 1.18 is taken. Any advises how to fix it?

the current version of GitLab and gitlab-runner is version 16.xxx. You generally should ensure that the major version of GitLab runners are the same as the GitLab instance you are using.

Right, I have downloaded the GitLab runner in the same version which GitLab. Installation seems to be okay, but when trying to register the runner I got message like this:
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner={here'stheid} status=200 OK
PANIC: Failed to register the runner.
Nothhing more explicit. Network is okay. How to debug it?
